# Are scores stacked when playing with 2 people in Centipede?

Tags: centipede

Do the scores stack when two people are playing in the 1998 PC version of Centipede? I'm not sure because when my brother and I played we would receive different exp with saving wee people. So if the exp does stack do you also get the free life every 20 thousand points as well?